# My Fetched Data isn't Storing in the State

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch

As the title suggests my fetched data isn't storing in the state. I think it is something to do with the loading sequence but I can't be sure because I am still new, especially when it comes to axios fetching. Using the useEffect to check the state I see that formData.organizer starts empty, get the userId string, then gets emptied again.

usersController

```
exports.myAccount = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.find({ email: req.email }, { _id: 1 });

    res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      user,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: err,
    });
  }
};
```

Create Event Container

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
...
organizer: '',
})

useEffect(() => {
 getMyAccount();
}, []);

const getMyAccount = async () => {
    let data;
    try {
      const res = await axiosPrivate.get('/api/users/myaccount');
      data = await res.data.user[0]._id;

      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        organizer: data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

useEffect(() => {
console.log(`organizer in formData:${formData.organizer}`);
  }, [formData.organizer]);
```

```
import axios from 'axios';
const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const axiosPrivate = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I figured a work around, which was to store the organizer ID in a separate state and then use that state to join the formData when making the put request. I cant seem to figure out how to prevent the organizer ID from getting wiped in the formData state. I am all ears if someone can explain! Failure is the greatest teacher as they say so the lesson wont be lost on me!

Comment: I don't understand your "Create Event Container" code: where is the actual code around it to handle import/exports and make this a React functional component? Also not sure about that axios code, that's going to run on import, instead of when told to actually run - always a bad idea to write code that has import side effects.